# On click navbar remains hidden when I resize page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to do a toggle button for my navbar. On screens smaller then 667px I want to hide my navbar and show toggle button. On click it should show and hide navbar li.

Toggle button works fine on `max-width: 667px` but when I resize, navbar remains hidden on screen width bigger then 667px

HTML

```
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" width="125px" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="slide">
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>  
                    </ul>
                    <a class="navbar-toggle">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </a> 
                </nav>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.slide {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 667px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .slide {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  
      $('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.slide').toggle();
        return false;
      });

});
```

Comment: Use ```min-width``` declaration where the menu needs to be visible, it remains hidden because you set it to ```display:none``` by toggling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `!important` flag for `min-width` and it should work fine:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 667px) {
  .slide {
    display: block!important;
  }
}
```

```js
$('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.slide').toggle();
        return false;
      });
```

```css
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.slide {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 667px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .slide {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 667px) {
  .slide {
    display: block!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-SfTiTlX6kk+qitfevl/7LibUOeJWlt9rbyDn92a1DqWOw9vWG2MFoays0sgObmWazO5BQPiFucnnEAjpAB+/Sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" width="125px" alt="logo"></a>
      </div>
      <nav>
          <ul class="slide">
              <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>  
          </ul>
          <a class="navbar-toggle">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </a> 
      </nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a separate event listener that triggers a function whenever the event is emitted. jQuery offers functionality of listening to window resizing events, using .on('resize'). This fires whenever you resize the windows. Use this piece of code in your JavaScript file

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 667) {
        $('.slide').show();
    }
});
```